# Change initial size of view after programm start (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

When I start my program, the initialized perspective has a ViewPart on the left and an EditorPart on the right. I'd like to have the initialized ViewPart a bit bigger.
Google didn't help me and Eclipse ignores this command when initializing the window:

```
IFolderLayout menu = layout.createFolder(
            "at.ticketline.kuenstler.left_folder", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f,
            editorArea);
```

This command works to set the size in every perspective but in the start perspective.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(true);
    layout.setFixed(true);

    IFolderLayout menu = layout.createFolder(
            "at.ticketline.kassa.left_folder", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f,
            editorArea);
    menu.addView(UebersichtView.ID);

}
```

So I once again, tried to change the perspective on start.

Different perspective on start: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBaQj.png
Normal size of the view if it isn't used for start perspective: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGQqV.png

So to sum it up again, the perspective I use for start always has a smaller view than it normally has.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the view has been added to the folder, then the view can be made larger by changing `0.25f` (=25%) to `0.30f` or `0.40f` (30-40%). Read [Using Perspectives in the Eclipse UI](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html) for a dated, but still current description.

Note that if you have the workbench state in `ApplicationWorkbenchAdapter` then you have to reset the perspective before the new size will matter...

Comment: The problem: I have ALL my perspectives on 0.25f. But when I click through the coolbar all views are bigger than the one that is generated on programm start.

Comment: edit: Eclipse simply ignores the size I want on the start perspective. It doesn't matter which perspective I set as start perspective. The start perspective is always smaller than it should be.

Comment: Please add the complete code for `Perspective.createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout)`.

Comment: Thanks for caring for my problem. I edited my question and added code + 2 screenshots.

Comment: Puzzling... Does your workbench change size as part of the start up sequence? In that case, the view _might_ be initially sized for a different size of the workbench. Try to add `ControlListener` to the view `Composite` and the workbench window `Shell`..

Comment: I added the ControlListener to the Composite of the view of the start perspective. When I start the program, the syso I added to "controlResized" was printed twice. If I use a different start perspective and call the former perspective via the toolbar, the syso is printed once.
I also added the Listener to the Shell in postWindowCreate(), "controlResized" isn't called there.
I removed the `menu.addView(...)` of my perspective to have a look at the size view on program start. The empty ViewPart has the same size like when there is a view in. I guess, the small size happens on the program start?

Comment: I agree... I have no ideas what is going on here. Sorry. I have never seen this problem in any of my RCP applications (15++ so far and still counting).